# How to create chat bubble tail in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, chat, whatsapp

I am trying to create a chat bubble tail that whats app uses in android. Didn't find any result about creating it manually.

[image]

Comment: Try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_bubble

Comment: Does it support adding `time` and `checkmark` functions?

Comment: That's something you'll have to implement, the package just help you with the UI.

Comment: I've coded a chat bubble that handles everything except the pointy tail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `flutter_chat_bubble` along with stack to implement `time` and `delivery indicator`. Thanks for the qucik reply
[Alejandro Cumpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2789300/alejandro-cumpa)